# Heroku subdomains redirect

Tags: api, heroku, dns, procfile

So, I have the domain api.suapraia.org that is config as a custom domain of my heroku app.

But when I send a request on my new domain to a resource that is exposed on the api(api.suapraia.org **/some_resource**) heroku redirects to suapraia-api.herokuapp.com **//some_resource**

Is there something that I need to do on domain config?

Comment: Heroku itself won't perform a redirect. What framework is your application using?

Comment: I'm using Flask! Here is what is hapenning when sending a POST request do the new domain: 1-POST on **new_domain/some_resource**. 2-POST gets redirected to **default_domain//some_resource** and becomes a GET

Comment: You can't redirect a POST, so that may be an issue.

Comment: So I can't use my app at my new domain, as heroku redirects? Or can I use my subdomain api.suapraia as a domain for my app without any redirect?

Comment: How are you redirecting users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted all my godaddy's config and started out from 0 following this post on Heroku's blog: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/10/7/heroku_casts_setting_up_custom_domains

It is all working now